# Making a django attribute an abstract property

Tags: django, python-3.6

I have a parent class which should be inherited by child classes that will become Django models. The child classes all have a common property `x`, so it should be an abstract property of the parent. The thing that differs between the children, is whether the property is a django model attribute or if it is directly set.

```
class A(Model, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    x = "hello"

class C(A):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='defaultC')

class D(A):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='defaultD')
```

So in my example, for some child classes the property `x` is known, but in other cases it needs to be selected. But one certain thing is that all descendants of the class `A` need an `x` attribute as it is a common property that must be defined by any descendants.

The problem is that if I ever instantiate a class of `C` or `D`, I get the following:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract methods x
```

I think the issue is something behind the scenes with Django's metaclass. It removes any django model attributes and replaces them with deferred attributes, or something, and so the property is never actually defined.

I can try moving the model attribute up to class `A` and let the children class override as a static value as need be:

```
class A(Model, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    x = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class B(A):
    x = "hello"

class C(A):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='defaultC')

class D(A):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='defaultD')
```

My issue with that is that this doesn't feel very abstract. `C` and `D` still need to override `x` to set their defaults and max length. It also worries me that people using class `A` generically in code will assume attribute `x` will be a django database field; when instead sometimes it can be a static string value.

What is the ideal approach here? Really I'd like to achieve my first example is possible.

Comment: I think you'd be better off making the method something like `get_x` and let the descendants decide for themselves whether that method returns a hard-coded value or the contents of a field.